# How to access a variable outside a class and function?

Tags: python

I would like to call a variable defined in a function within a class. Here is what I have

```
class StatePDFs:
    def __init__(self):
    example = "test test"

    def ca_form(self, data):

        #...other code...

        self.template='original_forms/state/CA/2021-541-k-1.pdf'

        self.data = {
            start_date:data['start'],
            end_date:data['end']
            #...    
        }

statePDF = StatePDFs()
ca_forms = statePDF.ca_form(data)
ca_data = ca_forms.data
ca_template = ca_forms.template
out_file = 'ca_test.pdf'

generated_pdf = pypdftk.fill_form(ca_template, ca_data, out_file=out_file, flatten=True)
```

When I do this I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

This is a simple example of what I am trying to do. In my actual code, the function retrieves data from MySQL and other sources. But I would like to have nested objects/variables like in the example above and call them from that function. I hope this makes sense. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is a snipe

Comment: `house()` doesn't return anything. Therefore `h` is being set to `None`. Hence, `h` not having the property `color`, because it's, you know, `None`. `m.color` would work fine though. Maybe your [mre] just needs some reworking so that we can see the actual issue you're talking about, since this seems like a really basic mistake.

Comment: It's not clear what your misunderstanding is, or what you mean by a "nested variable". Your `house` method returns `None`. So of course, when you do `h = m.house()` then `h` will be the object `None`. You could return *some other value*, e.g. `self`, in which case, `h = m.house()` will make `h` simply refer to the same object as `m`... and subsequently, it will have a `.color` attribute. But it isn't clear why you don't just use `m.color`

Comment: As mentioned, your code gives `m` the `color` and `rooms` attributes. This is just a guess, but are you trying to make `m` create and return a separate `House` object that has those attributes instead?

Comment: Sorry for the bad example. I have updated my question with an actual snippet from my script. @RandomDavis

Comment: `example` is indented incorrectly. If it's supposed to be in `__init__`, it's unused, so why is it there at all?

Comment: The question is still unclear. Everything Random said still applies. What are you actually trying to accomplish? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). As well, for a [mre], you need to add complete code (i.e. define `start_date, end_date, data, pypdftk`) and desired output. It's also best to include the full error message with traceback.

Comment: Minor note on terminology: you don't typically `call a variable`. You access a member (or an attribute) of an object. You would call a method on a variable or you would call a function, passing a variable.

Comment: I am creating a function for each state which should return items 1. PDF template path `ca_forms.template` 2. a dictionary that maps the data to the PDF template fields `ca_forms.data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I don't think I was clear in my questions but what I needed was to return multiple values from my function.

I added:

`return self.template, self.data`

then when calling the function I defined my variables in tuples:

`ca_template, ca_data = statePDF.ca_form(data)`